# php oo: why does this code prints only the first objects?

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php
//firt class of eitay

class hello
    {
        //hello word.
        public $first = 'hello world';

        public function first_method()
        {
            $a = 1;
            $b = 2;
            $c = $a + $b;
            return $c;
            return $this->first;
        }
    }

    $momo = new hello();
    print $momo->first_method();
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. that was very helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

It only prints `$c` because the function returns after that. When you return a function (in this case you `return $c`), it will stop executing and return to the calling function.

Answer (score 3):

A method returns only once and immediately. Multiple return statements are redundant, as only the first is executed.

If you want to return multiple results, you can utilize an associative array:

```
return array(
    "result" => $my_result,
    "time" => $end_time - $start_time
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should print `3` as the first `return` exits the function and output is `$c` which has value `3`

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call. return will also end the execution of
>   an eval() statement or script file.
>
> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script
>   file is ended. If the current script file was included or required,
>   then control is passed back to the calling file. Furthermore, if the
>   current script file was included, then the value given to return will
>   be returned as the value of the include call. If return is called from
>   within the main script file, then script execution ends. If the
>   current script file was named by the auto_prepend_file or
>   auto_append_file configuration options in php.ini, then that script
>   file's execution is ended.

so it is impossible for that to happen
have a test: http://ideone.com/HhzQa

Answer (score 0):

*As what others have said php is returning the first return it sees.*

I also have to ask why you are not treating the method like an object & more of an encapsulation of a function.

If you want to create multiple values within a method just assign them to the object scope with `$this` then as long as the property is public (public by default) you can access the property from outside the class, here is an example:

```
<?php 
class hello{
    public $first = 'hello world';

    function first_method(){
        $this->a = 1;
        $this->b = 2;
        $this->c = $this->a + $this->b;
    }

    function add_more($key, $value){
        $this->$key += $value;
    }
}

$momo = new hello();

$momo->first_method();

echo $momo->first; //hello world
echo $momo->a; //1
echo $momo->b; //2
echo $momo->c; //3

//Alter the propery with a method
$momo->add_more('a', 5); //1+5=6
$momo->add_more('b', 53);//2+53=55
echo $momo->a;//6
echo $momo->b;//55
?>
```

Passing about arrays is not oop.